# Eclipse upgrade killed PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I just upgraded my version of Eclipse on Ubuntu, and now whenever I open a Python file it opens in an external window, and the existing Python files I have open in Eclipse say "Could not open the editor: No editor descriptor for id org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor".

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Eclipse and the PyDev plugin, and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is Pydev a plugin, you may have to find the pydev plugin and install it.

Comment: It is.  I did.  It didn't help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971962/pydev-not-working-in-eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience (~8 years) with eclipse don't do in place updates. Always install a fresh version with a new workspace. And re-checkout projects from SCM.

Check first whether all required plugins still work before switching to the new environment.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your Java version is correct (what your version of PyDev is expecting). 
After I updated PyDev (5 min ago) I had the exact same error message displayed in the tabs where I once had python source files opened (No editor descriptor for id).

I updated my Java version from 1.7 to 1.8 with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Then to check your version, run:

```
java -version
```

You should see something like:

```
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)
```

Re-opened eclipse, and the PyDev plugin is working. Yay!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you install Eclipse new version then new plugins are installed which lead to change in ubuntu libraries and installing again will not take effect until you install new plugin which is supported

Comment: I have uninstalled and reinstalled the PyDev plugin, and it didn't help.

Comment: installing and uninstalling will not help, because there are still some files left , u need to purge all files related to it..may be it will help.. `sudo apt-get purge (software name)`..

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, when I updgradet PyDev with newest version 3.*. It needs java 1.7, but I have only java 1.6, so it does not work at all. I uninstalled it and set eclipse to old updating point, but nothing helped. Advise is to use PyDev versio 2.82. You can not find it from update repositories.

Only way is to download old version 2.8.2 from PyDev site, unzip that zip file to eclipse's drop in directory, in linux it is /usr/lib/eclipse/dropins. After unzipping you should see there features- and plugins-directories. And after some starting of eclipse, I could see PyDev again. At first restart of eclipse I could not see PyDev and tried "Check updates" and "Install new software" settind url to /usr/lib/eclipse/dropins but they did not see any software there. But trying to restart few times, old PyDevc 2.8.2 was in eclipse again. Huh.

I disabled PyDev from eclipses "check uopdates" so I don't make that error again, this machine will not get java 1.7 (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS).

Answer (score 0):

I now ran into exactly the same problem when updating to PyDev 5.0 and its definitely an issue that the user is not warned that the program might break on update. However, the simplest solution is to install the new required Java and JRE version, for PyDev 5.0 that's Java 8 and OpenJDK 1.8 (on Linux), and tell Eclipse to actually use the new JRE in the `eclipse.ini` file, by pointing it to the right path. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM on how to achieve this.