# Pydev missing after upgrading Eclipse on FreeBSD

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I recently updated my ports on my FreeBSD 9.0 release machine and I think eclipse was upgraded due to a port upstream forced Eclipse to be rebuilt. Now Pydev is gone. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling Eclipse, then installing Pydev using pydev.org/updates inside Eclipse. It appears to install ok but I can't create a Pydev project or use the Pydev view. I tried removing my ~/.eclipse folder to force the creation of a new one, and reinstalling Eclipse and Pydev to no avail. What am I doing wrong? I'm running Eclipse Indigo version 3.7.1 build id: R3_7_1

[This question was most similar to mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540050/eclipse-upgrade-killed-pydev), but the solution didn't work for me. I also tried pointing my install site as: http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml per another question on StackOverflow, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more testing I finally got the newest FreeBSD port to work. I had to launch and install the plugins as root. It didn't work another time I ran it but, this [great troubleshooting document](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html) helped out. I methodically went through each step one by one, and the logs indicated there was an error on my /usr/local/lib file it was trying to unzip. My user doesn't have write access to that directory but root does. I don't know why it didn't work the last time I ran it as root, perhaps I didn't install the plug-in as root. It works now, so I'm happy. Thanks Fabio, for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how FreeBSD packages things, so, maybe an easy way out would be getting Eclipse from Eclipse.org and installing PyDev on that fresh install (or if you're also doing web stuff, I'd suggest grabbing Aptana Studio 3, which comes with PyDev preinstalled, so, you don't have to worry about configuring it).

See: http://pydev.org/download.html for details

Comment: I used the [FreeBSD Ports system](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html), which compiles directly from source. I think an upgrade of a library or binary that eclipse depends on may have broken it. The weird thing is that pydev appears to install correctly but I don't see it in the Plugins tab on the installed software page. I may have to move on to another IDE, as much as it pains me. :(