# PyDev not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I recently had to reset my PC and I get this error after relaunching Eclipse:

> No editor descriptor for id org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor

I tried searching for a solution but others like 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540050/eclipse-upgrade-killed-pydev) have been caused by upgrading Eclipse. I'm new to Eclipse and programming in general. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: May be here something helpful can be found: http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/discussion/293649/thread/de2736b5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update** Java **11** now required for PyDev. Rest of answer preserved as still relevant.

Two things to check:

1. Check that you are running Java 7 or greater and newish Eclipse. From [PyDev requirements](http://www.pydev.org/download.html):

> Requirements
>
> Java 7: Important: If you don't have java 7, the update process may
> appear to succeed, but PyDev will simply not show in the target
> installation. See PyDev does not appear after install! below for
> details on how to fix that. At least one of:
>
> Python (2.2 or newer) Jython (2.2 or newer) IronPython (2.6 or newer)
> and
>
> Eclipse (3.8/4.3 onwards) Note if using Eclipse standalone: Python and
> IronPython require only the Platform Runtime Binary (download around
> 45-50 MB), and Jython also requires JDT.

2. Make sure you have PyDev appears properly installed:
3. *Help* menu
4. *Installation Details*
5. *Plug-ins* tab
6. type `pydev` in the filter box (see below)
7. check that PyDev is installed

[image]

If PyDev is not installed, and you have met the requirements, try installing it again from http://pydev.org/updates Update Site:

1. *Help* menu
2. *Install New Software*
3. Put `http://pydev.org/updates` in the *Work With* box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (see screenshot below)
4. Select PyDev in the list
5. Complete the wizard
6. Restart Eclipse when prompted, and voila (I hope!) you have PyDev working again.

[image]

If your problem is not resolved with the above, please provide more details in the question

Answer (score 1):

Currently (January 2022) the update the eclipse to the newest https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-12/ and https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest helped, but also Java 11 (I'm using Oracle Java at Ubuntu 18) was required. At the webpage of PyDev the minimal versions are given.